# Hangouts Chat API - No Display Name for Room

Tags: google-hangouts

It is evident from the documentation that a space will have a `displayName` only if it is of type ROOM.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces#Space

However sometimes I receive the `addedToSpace` event request from hangouts chat without a `displayName` in the `space` object, even if the space type is a ROOM. 
Is that in any way possible? Please help me out !

Comment: Hello @HariHaraSudan, can you please provide more information about your question? What do you mean by "sometimes", when does this particular behavior occur? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 The issue is sporadic. I cant replicate it from Hangouts chat UI, but i receive requests without `displayName`. Is this in any way possible ?

Comment: What's the exact use case for using display name?

Comment: I need to save the display name in db to list the available rooms to the users in ui.

Comment: Hello @HariHaraSudan, how are you trying to retrieve the `displayName`? Could you provide more information? Also, can you confirm that you are trying to get the `displayName` of a `ROOM` indeed? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer guys. If the room is a group, then there will be no display name for the same. Hence no display name is available. However, the group members are not sent via the request. Anyways, Thank you all for your help.